# Проблема с иконками при hover

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Надо из такой картинки сделать при наведении вот такую

```css
.header-list
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    padding-left: 0
    list-style-type: none
    margin: 0
    &__item
        margin-left: 30px
        &:first-child
            margin-left: 0
        i
            font-size: 40px
            &:hover
                background-color: #fff
                color: blue
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
                <span class="header-left-title">вступить в наши группы</span>
                <ul class="header-list">
                    <li class="header-list__item">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-list__item">
                        <i class="fab fa-telegram"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-list__item">
                        <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-list__item">
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо из такой картинки сделать при наведении вот такую

Comment: Ужасный код - исправьте пример.

Comment: Павел Игоревич что ужасного я писал на sass ?

Comment: У вас 2 дива не закрыты даже в примере. Зачем вы задаете `display: flex` - для списка?

Comment: в структуре html все норм, так скопировал

Comment: display: flex чтобы встал в строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.header-list__item {
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.header-list__item:hover > i {
  opacity: 0;
}
.header-list__item:hover > img {
  opacity: 1;
}
.header-list:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.header-list i {
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.header-list img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <span class="header-left-title">вступить в наши группы</span>
  <ul class="header-list">
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iaXNvLTg4NTktMSI/PjxzdmcgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MTIgNTEyIiBzdHlsZT0iZW5hYmxlLWJhY2tncm91bmQ6bmV3IDAgMCA1MTIgNTEyOyIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PHBhdGggc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzRENkZBOTsiIGQ9Ik00NzYuNjksNTEySDM1LjMxQzE1Ljg5LDUxMiwwLDQ5Ni4xMSwwLDQ3Ni42OVYzNS4zMUMwLDE1Ljg5LDE1Ljg5LDAsMzUuMzEsMEg0NzYuNjlDNDk2LjExLDAsNTEyLDE1Ljg5LDUxMiwzNS4zMVY0NzYuNjlDNTEyLDQ5Ni4xMSw0OTYuMTEsNTEyLDQ3Ni42OSw1MTIiLz48cGF0aCBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojRkZGRkZGOyIgZD0iTTQzMi41NTIsODguMjc2djg4LjI3NmgtNzkuNDQ4Yy05LjcxLDAtMTcuNjU1LDcuOTQ1LTE3LjY1NSwxNy42NTV2NTIuOTY2aDg4LjI3NnY4OC4yNzZoLTg4LjI3NlY1MTJoLTg4LjI3NlYzMzUuNDQ4aC03MC42MjF2LTg4LjI3Nmg3MC42MjF2LTUyLjk2NmMwLTU1LjYxNCw0Mi4zNzItMTAxLjUxNyw5Ny4xMDMtMTA1LjkzMUg0MzIuNTUyeiIvPjxnPjwvZz48Zz48L2c+PGc+PC9nPjxnPjwvZz48Zz48L2c+PGc+PC9nPjxnPjwvZz48Zz48L2c+PGc+PC9nPjxnPjwvZz48Zz48L2c+PGc+PC9nPjxnPjwvZz48Zz48L2c+PGc+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==" />
    </li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <i class="fab fa-telegram"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Добавил сюда скомпилированный код, потому что нет компиляторов на stackoverflow.

Сделал для первой иконки, дальше по аналогии. То что картинка скачет при наведении это потому что нужно подобрать такую же по размерам, на Font Awesome я не нашел цветных вариантов, поэтому нужно использовать сторонние иконки (в виде SVG например).

Ниже код SASS:

```
.header-list
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  padding-left: 0
  list-style-type: none
  margin: 0
  &__item
    margin-left: 30px
    position: relative
    &:hover
      > i
        opacity: 0
      > img
        opacity: 1
  &:first-child
    margin-left: 0
  i
    font-size: 40px
    opacity: 1
    transition: 0.5s
  img
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    opacity: 0
    transition: 0.5s
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Я правильно понял мне нужную иконку надо вырезать и превратить в svg и вставить ?

Comment: Alexandr Tovmach  вот иконки цветные

Comment: https://www.flaticon.com/search?word=instagram

Comment: Я тоже с flaticon взял, но как видно размеры не сходятся идеально, поэтому или искать идеально под размер, или же не использовать Font Awesome, и просто взять из одной коллекции с Flaticon.

>Я правильно понял мне нужную иконку надо вырезать и превратить в svg и вставить ?
не обязательно вырезать, можно как я сказал выше взять готовые, толкьо чтоб размеры сошлись

Comment: Alexandr Tovmach ок спасибо

Comment: Возникла проблема при наведении на иконку иконка плавно превращается в другую, но при нажатии я не могу перейти на другую страницу подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить ?

Comment: я в примерах не видел ссылок, но если включить экстрасенсорные способности, то скорее всего нужно обернуть обе иконки в тег <a>

Comment: ясно спасибо не знал что ссылка в ссылке это нормально. Я могу ошибаться но видел видео в котором была такая проблема и ее как-то по другому решили

Comment: так, стоп ссылка в ссылке это не нормально)
я имею ввиду:  

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <span class="header-left-title">вступить в наши группы</span>
      <ul class="header-list">
        <li class="header-list__item">
          <a>
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
            <img src="/путь_к_иконке" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

Comment: Так у меня так и сделано, но при появлении img теперь не могу перейти на соц  сеть

Comment: можно код глянуть гдето? лучше на codepen

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ge052s1y/ вот решение это я слепой

Comment: да да, я уже и там ответ сделал)

Comment: еще раз спасибо

Comment: Have a nice day!

Comment: Alexandr Tovmach
thank